# log_loss from sklearn gives nan, while tensorflow.losses.log_loss works

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn, log-likelihood

I have a binary classification problem.
I am using the log_loss from `tensorflow.losses.log_loss`.

To check, I use `sklearn.metrics.log_loss`. Most of the times, the two functions give the same result (only difference in dtype). In some instance, the `sklearn` function returns `NaN` while `tf.losses.log_loss` returns a correct value.

data is here:
https://pastebin.com/BvDgDnVT

code:

```
import sklearn.metrics
import tensorflow as tf
y_true = [... see pastebin link]
y_pred = [... see pastebin link]
loss_sk = sklearn.metrics.log_loss(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0, 1]) # -> returns NaN
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loss_tf = tf.losses.log_loss(y_true, y_pred).eval(session=sess) # -> returns 0.0549
```

There seems to be some `log(0)` happening, but why does tensorflow not have this problem?

Comment: This looks like you've stumbled across a bug as I get the same result. It looks like some form of overflow, as taking subsections of the list works fine, so it's not one particular value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the dtype of both arrays to a 64-bit float fixes it

```
dtype=np.float64
```

for example adding `y_pred = y_pred.astype(np.float64)`

Comment: Why? I just stumbled on this problem too, but curiously converting my numpy arrays to pandas Series of dtype float64 fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Another way of fixing the issue is to provide `eps=1e-7` to `log_loss`, which is a more appropriate epsilon for `float32` and is what tensorflow's using.
Scikit however uses `1e-15` as a default (expecting `float64`).

Comment: Thank you! I was using scikit-learn `permutation_importance` and gets NaNs for importance because of this. Setting eps in scorer fixes the issue. :)